# How to implement Processor API with Exactly-once mode

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm studying Kafka Stream and using Processor API to implement my use case. The code below shows the Process method which forwards a message downstream and aborts before calling `commit`. This causes the stream to be reprocessed and duplicates the message on the Sink.

```
public void process(String key, String value) {

    context.forward(key, value);

    .. 
    ..
    //killed

    context.commit();
}
```

processing.guarantee parameter:

```
streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.PROCESSING_GUARANTEE_CONFIG, StreamsConfig.EXACTLY_ONCE);
```

Is there a way to apply the forwarding only when invoking `commit` statement. If not, what is the correct approach to implement Exactly-once mode.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your sink is in `read_committed` consumer mode so it will only see committed messages. If messages were written to the output topic before the transaction was aborted, then upon abort, the messages are still there, just not marked at committed. The second time through the transaction completes so the messages and a commit marker are added to the output topic. If you read without being in `read_committed` mode then you will see all messages (including uncommitted ones) and it may appear as duplicates because you see the aborted results and the committed results.

From the 0.11 javadoc here https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

> Transactions were introduced in Kafka 0.11.0 wherein applications can
>   write to multiple topics and partitions atomically. In order for this
>   to work, consumers reading from these partitions should be configured
>   to only read committed data. This can be achieved by by setting the
>   isolation.level=read_committed in the consumer's configuration.
>
> In read_committed mode, the consumer will read only those
>   transactional messages which have been successfully committed. It will
>   continue to read non-transactional messages as before. There is no
>   client-side buffering in read_committed mode. Instead, the end offset
>   of a partition for a read_committed consumer would be the offset of
>   the first message in the partition belonging to an open transaction.
>   This offset is known as the 'Last Stable Offset'(LSO).
>
> A read_committed consumer will only read up till the LSO and filter out
>   any transactional messages which have been aborted. The LSO also
>   affects the behavior of seekToEnd(Collection) and
>   endOffsets(Collection) for read_committed consumers, details of which
>   are in each method's documentation. Finally, the fetch lag metrics are
>   also adjusted to be relative to the LSO for read_committed consumers.
>   Partitions with transactional messages will include commit or abort
>   markers which indicate the result of a transaction. There markers are
>   not returned to applications, yet have an offset in the log. As a
>   result, applications reading from topics with transactional messages
>   will see gaps in the consumed offsets. These missing messages would be
>   the transaction markers, and they are filtered out for consumers in
>   both isolation levels. Additionally, applications using read_committed
>   consumers may also see gaps due to aborted transactions, since those
>   messages would not be returned by the consumer and yet would have
>   valid offsets.

Answer (score -1):

You may like to wrap context.commit() under finally block to make sure that it gets called. However, you also need to ensure that this is indeed called after successful processing.

Comment: Hi Sunil, that only works when the process stopped gracefully.